# Get custom attribute dropdown/multiselect options label and value in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I created customer custom attribute with input multiselect like this:

```
$code = 'multiselect_test';
$insertData = array(
        "type"     => "text",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => 'Multiselect Input',
        "input"    => 'multiselect',
        "source"   => "",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => false,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""
      );
       $values = array('Briteny','James');
       $insertData['source'] = 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table';
       $insertData['backend'] = 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend';
       $insertData['option']['values'] = $values;


$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $code,  $insertData);
      $attribute   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $code);

      $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $code);
      $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
      $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register"; 
      $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit"; 
      $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
      ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
      ->setData("is_system", 0)
      ->setData("is_user_defined", 1) 
      ->setData("sort_order", $data['sorting_order']);

    try {
      $attribute->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $this->_logger->addError($e->getMEssage());
    }
```

i created a custom input for customer registration form in frontend for that custom attribute like this:

```
<select multiple name="multiselect_test">
  <option value="0">Britney</option>
  <option value="1">James</option>
</select>
```

when i looked in backend to edit the customer info in account information the custom attribute input value from frontend was not there, i guess it's because the value for this custom attribute is wrong (not 0 or 1), then i try to insert the value from backend and save it, and the input value save properly, when i try to retrieve the value like this:

```
$cattrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('multiselect_test')->getValue();
```

i got this result :

```
39,40
```

In conclusion  **i need to know how to retrieve this multiselect/dropdown custom attribute real value and label information**, so i can use it to create custom attribute input for customer registration properly, or use it for other process in backend

Comment: try with,  $customer->getCustomAttribute('multiselect_test')->getLabel();

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya i want to retrieve each option from select input label, not the general label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use eav atrribute interface to retrieve available options for your dropdown/multiselect like this:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepository
    ) {
        $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepository; 
    }

public function retrieveOptions($custom_attribute_code){
        $attributes = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $custom_attribute_code);
        $options = $attributes->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code to get and set custom attribute value.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
    foreach ($customerObj as $customerObjdata) {

        $customermodel  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
        $customerData = $customermodel->getDataModel();
        $customerData->setId($customerObjdata->getData('entity_id'));
        $customerData->setCustomAttribute('is_vendor', 0);
        $customermodel->updateData($customerData);

        $customerResource = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory')->create();
        $customerResource->saveAttribute($customermodel, 'is_vendor');
    }
```

Comment: Why not using dependency injection?